# When I change the value of an input clicking on a button $bindTo doesn't work firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

So I'm beginner to angularjs and firebase and I'm trying to develop an app which adds values(numerical) on an input. So far I have this:

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['firebase']);

app.directive('addOne', function() { 
    return {
        link: function(scope,element) {
            element.bind('click', function() {
                console.log(element.parent().find('input'))
                element.parent().find('input')[1].value++;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

and my view:

```
<section class="form-group">
   <label for="">$</label> <input type="button" value="+" add-one>
   <input ng-model="user.level" type="text" class="form-control" />
</section>
```

and my controller:

```
app.controller('mController', ['$scope', 'User',
    function($scope, backHome, User, adicionar){

        $scope.user = User(1);
        User(1).$bindTo($scope, "user");

    }
]);
```

the thing is that after I click the button with the directive add-one the value of the input changes but the $bindTo is not working...

So why does the bindTo doesn't work when I make a change directly in the DOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularJS doesn't care what the value of an input is set to, it only cares about what's in the ng-model.  Try this...

```
app.directive('addOne', function() { 
    return {
        link: function(scope,element) {
            element.on('click', function() {
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    scope.user.level++
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

As pointed out by @PankajParkar, you also need to use scope.$apply when you want to update a binding from event.

```js
angular.module('demo', [])
.controller('DemoController', function($scope){
  $scope.user={level: 1};
})
.directive('addOne', function() { 
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.on('click', function() {
        scope.$apply(scope.user.level++);
      });
    }
  }
})
.directive('unaryInput', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      model: "=",
      txt: '@buttonText'
    },
    template: '<input type="text" ng-model="model" /><button>{{txt}}</button>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        if(angular.isDefined(attrs.initialVal)) {
          scope.model = attrs.initialVal;
        }
      
        element.on('click', function() {
          if (attrs.direction === 'decrement') {
            scope.$apply(scope.model--);
          } else {
            scope.$apply(scope.model++);
          }
        });
      
      }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="DemoController">
  <input type="text" ng-model="user.level">
  <input type="button" value="+" add-one>
  <hr>
  <unary-input button-text="Add one" model="user.level" direction="increment"></unary-input>
  <unary-input button-text="-" model="user.level" direction="decrement"></unary-input>
  <hr>
  <unary-input button-text="-" model="user.val" direction="decrement" initial-val="10"></unary-input>
</div>
```

In AngularJS, you want to change the view by changing the model that it's based on, versus doing it imperatively like you might with a traditional jQuery approach for example (traversing the DOM and incrementing the value).

**UPDATE**

Okay, so here's a nice reusable version of the (**please check the snippet to see it in action**).

The template includes both the button and the input.  It accepts 4 values that you set as attributes:

1. button-text: The text you want to show on the button.
2. model: The model value for the input.
3. initial-val: The initial value for the input if you don't want to initialize on your controller.
4. direction: Whether to increment or decrement the values.  This one currently accepts a string "decrement" to subtract.  If you have no direction set or any other value set in the attribute, it will increment.

So, you would use it like this:

```
<unary-input button-text="Subtract One" model="user.val" direction="decrement" initial-val="10"></unary-input>
```

And the directive itself looks like this:

```
.directive('unaryInput', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      model: "=",
      txt: '@buttonText'
    },
    template: '<input type="text" ng-model="model" /><button>{{txt}}</button>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        if(angular.isDefined(attrs.initialVal)) {
          scope.model = attrs.initialVal;
        }

        element.on('click', function() {
          if (attrs.direction === 'decrement') {
            scope.$apply(scope.model--);
          } else {
            scope.$apply(scope.model++);
          }
        });

      }
  };
});
```

Comment: hmmm, worked fine for me, but that's a more precise answer now. thanks!

Comment: Nice! I get what you said but... I confess that I should have specified better my problem.. so let's go:

I did in that way because I have more than one input with a increment button above it so the thing flux that I need is: get the closest input and increment its value.

So by doing in the way that you said I would have to have one directive for each input ?

Comment: The way it is now, yes. But, it could be made to be more reusable by using a template (which is what I would normally do).  Just in the middle of getting dinner organized.  I'll make a demo for you and update shortly.

Comment: Thanks!! Usually I get things fast.. all the knowledge that I have about angular is from codecademy I know what a template is but I do not always realize when I have to do one.. also angularjs is proving its weird line curve hehe...

Comment: Yeah, stick with it and one day it's just going to all click.  Listen this was a quick example, it could be much better.  In fact, I'd probably use ng-click on the button and in the link bind a function versus the event.  That would let you have a plus and a minus button in the same template.  You could even use an attribute that accepted plus, minus or both and add those as expressions on the buttons using ng-if to render one or both buttons.  Have fun with it and make it fit your needs!

Comment: I tried to upvote but it seens I do not have enough reputation... anyways  thanks very much for the attention!!!! I will make work here as I want !!

Comment: Understand if you can't upvote, but if it answered your question, could you select the answer as correct?

Comment: yeap, if it's the green check above the upvote arrows it's done :)

Answer (score 0):

Browsing around I could find a solution doing the way you said in the comments (two buttons one incrementing and another decrementing) thanks a lot for the help! and here's the final version.

```
app.directive('unaryInput', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {
                model: "="
            },
            template: '<input type="text" ng-model="model" /><button ng-click="decrement()">-</button><button ng-click="increment()">+</button>',
            link: function(scope, element) {
                scope.increment = function() {
                    scope.model++;
                }
                scope.decrement = function() {
                    scope.model--;
                }
            }
        };
    });
```